# YII2 Не сохраняются значения в сессии

Tags: php, yii2

Мне нужно сохранить значение в сессии после авторизации. Пишу:

```
Yii::$app->user->login($user, 3600 * 24);
Yii::$app->session['__param'] = '1111';
```

После этого кода в сессии:

```
array(4) { 
    ["__flash"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["__id"]=> int(1) 
    ["__param"]=> string(4) "1111" 
}
```

Перехожу на другую страницу, а в сессии нет моего параметра:

```
array(4) { 
    ["__flash"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["__id"]=> int(1) 
}
```

Почему сессия при каждом запросе затирается?

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает так:

```
**В одном контроллере:**
Yii::$app->session->set('test', 'test');

**В другом:**
print_r(Yii::$app->session->get('test')); // выведет "test"

**Но если вывести** 
print_r(Yii::$app->session); // действительно значения "test" мы не найдем
```

Comment: не работает никак: `Yii::$app->session->set('test', 'test');`,  `Yii::$app->session['test'] = 'test';`, `$_SESSION['test'] = 'test';`

Comment: Обратите внимание, как я вывожу нужные данные в моем ответе. Я вывожу не сессию, а конкретное значение через get('test') - так тоже не выводит? Если да, то у Вас вообще работают сессии? Не слетает ли авторизация?

Comment: вывожу либо через get  `Yii::$app->session->get('test')`, либо так `$_SESSION['test']`. Одно и то же. Сессии работают, авторизация не слетает. Такое ощущение что yii перезаписывает сессию каждый раз, оставляя там только __id и __flash.

Comment: Проверьте, где именно у Вас записываются данные в сессию. Дело в том, что сессия обновляется после логина, то есть если вы записываете данные в сессию, а потом делаете логин - данные слетят. Возможно не только логин может обновлять данные сессии

Comment: Делаю как в вопросе написано, т.е. после логина